# Quel est le COD dans « Il se rase la barbe » ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Dans une phrase comme :

> Il se rase la barbe.

Que représentent « se » et « la barbe » ? En particulier, quel est le *complément d'objet direct* ?

Je pose la question car dans la phrase :

> Il se rase.

le *complément d'objet direct* me semble être « se ». Or dans la première tournure, « la barbe » me parait bien mieux remplir ce rôle. Le « se » de la première phrase représente-t-il un autre élément grammatical ?

***Mise à jour***

Des éléments de réponse sur ce point dans : [Le groupe prépositionnel ne peut être complément direct ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/le-groupe-pr%C3%A9positionnel-ne-peut-%C3%AAtre-compl%C3%A9ment-direct)

Answer (score 8):

Dans cette phrase, le COD est « la barbe ».

En effet, le verbe *se raser* est pronominal.

On peut se poser la question suivante : « Que se rase-t-il ? » → « la barbe ».

Comment: Contrairement au deuxième point qui justifie pleinement que *la barbe* est le COD, l fait que *se raser* soit pronominal n'est pas un argument en soit, *se voir* est pronominal aussi mais dans ce cas le réfléchi est le COD.<br/>Pour compléter, le pronom *se* peut être COD ou COI suivant les constructions, mais dans ce cas précis, on peut dire *il se la rase* et le pronom *la* ne peut être que COD.

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce type particulier de constructions "pronominale" qui implique une partie du corps le pronom correspond toujours au possesseur de cette partie. Si on veut l'analyser ainsi, il faudrait dire que *se* est un complément indirect, voire carrément qu'il fait, en fait, partie du groupe nominal. Cela dépendra de la manière dont on choisit d’analyser une phrase comme *Il rase la barbe de Martin*.

Il s'agit en fait d'une expression de la [possession inaliénable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession) en français. [Cet article](https://www.usherbrooke.ca/catifq/fileadmin/sites/catifq/contributions/VINET_Possession.pdf) parle de plusieurs autres constructions où cette distinction est présente.

Comment: En suivant le même raisonnement, on pourrait dire que dans *Il se regarde dans le miroir*, *se* serait un complément indirect dans la mesure où l'on peut également dire *Il se regarde le bout du nez dans le miroir*. La transformation pronominale pour *se raser* pourrait être aussi bien ramenée de *Il rase Jean* (*Jean* COD), *Il le rase* (*le* COD)  à *Il se rase* (*se* COD).

Comment: @GAMPUB Je ne saisis absolument pas ce que vous essayez de démontrez. Je crois que vous n'avez melheureusement rien compris de la différence entre les deux constructions en question.